# Loop through IEnumerable using Lambda

Tags: c#, func

I have a func which looks like below

```
Func<Product, bool> ItemProduct(Iitem item) => (pro)=> pro.ItemID == item.Id;
```

I am looking for a func which take multiple items. I am trying like below but that is not correct...Can you please help me how to do this?

```
Func<Product, bool> ItemProduct(IEnumerable<Iitem> items) => (pro) => pro.ItemID == items.Id;
```

Comment: What is `ItemProduct(IEnumerable<Iitem> items)` expected to do/return?

Comment: Indeed - providing a [mcve] would really clarify this, and in coming up with it you may well answer your own question.

Comment: @YacoubMassad it should return IEnumerable<Product>

Comment: @reddy Do you want to return a function that returns true if *all* ids match, or if *any* id matches?

Comment: What do you mean by "that is not correct". What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Func<IEnumerable<Product>, bool> ItemProduct(IEnumerable<Iitem> items)...`. Give it a try.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett I am expecting to return all ids match should be retuned

Comment: @reddy Are you saying that you want to return a function which returns `true` if ALL ids match?

Comment: @SivaGopal i think you are correct i think it should be Func<IEnumerable<Product>, bool> ItemProduct(IEnumerable<Iitem> items)

Comment: @EdPlunkett I want it to return all Ids that are matching

Comment: @reddy So you want to return `Func<Product, IEnumerable<int>>`? The *second* type argument is what the function will return.

Answer (score 1):

From comments, it may be that you actually want to generate a function that will own an enumeration of `Iitem` and take a `Product` as a parameter, and will return all of its `Iitem`s whose `Id` matches the `ItemID` of the `Product`. That's this:

```
Func<Product, IEnumerable<Iitem>> ItemProduct(IEnumerable<Iitem> items) =>
    pro => items.Where(item => pro.ItemID == item.Id);
```

Used like so:

```
var someItems = new [] { new Iitem { Id = 1 }, new Iitem { Id = 2 } };

var f = ItemProduct(someItems);

var prod = new Product { ItemID = 1; }

//  Results will be an enumeration that will enumerate a single Iitem, the 
//  one whose Id is 1. 
var results = f(prod);
```

---

I'll leave my original guess here, because I'm still not sure what you really want.

This method will return a func that returns true if *all* Ids in `items` match the `ItemID` of the `Product` passed in as a parameter:

```
Func<Product, bool> ItemProduct(IEnumerable<Iitem> items) =>
    (pro) => items.All(item => pro.ItemID == item.Id);
```

Like so:

```
var product = new Product() { ItemID = 1 };
var itemColl1 = new Iitem[] { new Iitem { Id = 1 }, new Iitem { Id = 2 } };
var itemColl2 = new Iitem[] { new Iitem { Id = 1 }, new Iitem { Id = 1 } };

var f1 = ItemProduct(itemColl1);
var f2 = ItemProduct(itemColl2);

bool thisWillBeFalse = f1(product);
bool thisWillBeTrue = f2(product);
```

If you want the function to return true if at least one of the Ids matches, but not necessarily all of them, this would do that. The only difference is that `items.All()` changes to `items.Any()`:

```
Func<Product, bool> ItemProductAny(IEnumerable<Iitem> items) =>
    (pro) => items.Any(item => pro.ItemID == item.Id);
```

Like so:

```
var f3 = ItemProductAny(itemColl1);
var f4 = ItemProductAny(itemColl2);

bool thisWillAlsoBeTrue = f3(product);
bool thisWillAlsoBeTrueAgain = f4(product);


var itemColl3 = new Iitem[] { new Iitem { Id = 2 }, new Iitem { Id = 3 } };

var f5 = ItemProductAny(itemColl3);

bool butThisWillBeFalse = f5(product);
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem

Comment: @reddy Great. You should accept it as the correct answer in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to return a function which for a given product returns `true` if all items from a given set have the same `Id` as the product's `ItemID`, you may use `items.All(...)` instead of single ID comparison:

```
Func<Product, bool> ItemProduct1(IEnumerable<Iitem> items) 
    => (pro) => items.All(i => pro.ItemID == i.Id);
```

If you need `true` for products which `ItemID` matches `Id` of just some of the given items, use `items.Any(...)` instead:

```
Func<Product, bool> ItemProduct1(IEnumerable<Iitem> items) 
    => (pro) => items.Any(i => pro.ItemID == i.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem